# I want to set .MP4 file type in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, video, file-type, android-videoview

I am currently developing an app which when started, play a video on the current layout itself.

Android Studio is not identifying the .mp4 format and asks for file type associations. On selecting "Open in Associated Application", it will start a Media Player on my laptop.

I don't want the app to play using some other resource. It should play the .mp4 file on the layout itself.

Comment: can you show code for setting type of file and playing video file ?